# Why did the format of full-form URLs to answers change?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, answers, hyperlinks

As I pointed out in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313380/377214), the URL scheme for full-form links to answers has changed from:

```
https://site/questions/question-id/question-title/answer-id#answer-id
```

to:

```
https://site/questions/question-id/question-title#answer-id
```

Pretty much every link that redirects to an answer, including short-form links to answers (i.e. `https://site/a/answer-id`) and `?lastactivity` links to questions, for example, now redirect to the latter form of URL, instead of the former one. (Interestingly, the responses tab in one's own user profile still consists of hard links to the old form.)

Why was this change made? It seems to have [broken chat oneboxing and chat feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313359/377214), as those are still looking for the old form of URL. Additionally, as per Tim Stone's comment, it also seems to have [broken links to answers that aren't on the first page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313288/linking-to-lastactivity-breaks-when-that-activity-is-on-second-or-greater-page).

As a test for the above, I tried manually changing the URL to the old form, and it properly oneboxed in chat and properly changed the page and scrolled down.

It also briefly affected SmokeDetector (a community project that widely affects SE sites), until I filed an issue with them and had it fixed.

Was it done because search engines were showing multiple results, since it wasn't clear to them that they were looking at the same page since the URLs to answers were technically different?

Comment: It also seems to break for answers not on the first page ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Not being able to get to the new answer when you click on a front-page "answered" link is pretty frustrating. :-(

Comment: Looks to be unintentional, a side effect of an unrelated change. I've pinged the developer responsible.

Comment: @Shog9 What was this change related to?

Comment: I donno. Some slack thing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like an unintentional regression when adding some new Teams features - a fix has been deployed.