# Can't see other pages of answers on a certain deleted question

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

While browsing a [specific deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22795/323179) on MSE I noticed something strange: it's almost impossible to get to the second page of results. There are supposed to be 34 answers. The first page shows 30. I'm not sure why this is happening and I haven't been able to replicate this with any other question.

Clicking on ["2"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22795/best-place-to-meet-female-programmers-for-romance?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top) or "next" (which have the same URL) goes to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22795#tab-top which scrolls to "34 answers" and shows the first page of answers.

The revision history of one of the missing answers can be viewed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/22802/revisions). Clicking ["Return to Answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22795/best-place-to-meet-female-programmers-for-romance/22802#22802) goes to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22795#22802, which goes to the question, showing the first page of answers beneath.

---

Note: Because all these posts are deleted, you need 10k rep here to see them.

Comment: As an aside, while trying to repro this on mobile, I noticed that it displays "0 answers" despite being able to see the deleted answers, which looks really weird. But there are no spam/offensive deleted answers on tbat question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you clarify what you mean by redirect? Does clicking the link to another page just not properly add the page parameter to the URL, or is it literally redirecting from page 2 back to page 1, changing the URL?

Comment: @animuson I've found the bug's cause. Will post an answer with details.

Comment: FYI: The development branch of the [SOUP user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) now has a workaround for this. Try installing the development version and check to see if this issue still exists.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385951/page-2-and-up-of-answers-of-a-deleted-question-for-spam-offensive-doesnt-work

Answer (score 12):

I think I've discovered the cause of this bug. The post you linked not only has helpful spam or abuse flags, but it was also locked after being deleted, so the system treats it as if it were deleted as spam or abuse (those are locked at the same time as being deleted), and as such attempts to strip the title from the URL. The regex that removes the title from URLs of posts deleted as spam or abuse is a little bit too lenient: it also chops off query strings from the title when it shouldn't.

Most questions that are deleted (for any reason other than spam or abusive) don't have their URL title slug removed, and going to a short link or any link redirects to the full-form link that contains the title:

```
/questions/[post ID]/title-of-deleted-post
```

As an example, try clicking on this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321293. Even if you're a <10k user, the title of that deleted post will still be visible in the URL after the redirect.

In the past, this was true for all deleted questions. However, later on, spammers began to exploit this fact (e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234567), so the team decided to strip the URL slug out from such posts*. Therefore, links like:

```
/q/22795
```

or:

```
/questions/22795/placeholder-for-title-of-question
```

redirect to:

```
/questions/22795
```

This happens for all users, 10k+ or not.

The bug lies in the fact that when performing the title stripping, the system considers *everything after the ID* to be part of the title, and strips them out. This means that things like `?page=2` get stripped out.

I've discovered that the stripping logic does not take place if I manually remove the title from the URL, and links like:

```
/questions/22795?page=2
```

...work properly and go to the second page. Even if you insert a `/` between the post ID and the query string, it works correctly.

The pagination links, however, use the below type of link:

```
/questions/22795/placeholder-for-title-of-question?page=2
```

...which triggers the bug and everything after the post ID is stripped out.

I can think of a few possible fixes:

- Do not include the title URL slug in the pagination link if the post is considered to have been deleted as spam or abuse. This seems a little too specific for this edge case; it's extremely rare for a question with lots of answers to occupy multiple pages to be deleted as spam or abuse, or for it to be manually locked after being deleted.
- Do not include the title URL slug in the pagination link *at all*. This seems like it would result in too many redirects.
- Do not strip out titles from URLs if the user has 10k+ rep. This might be too complicated.
- Fix the stripping logic to not remove query strings. I think this is the best solution.

You may have noticed that fragments (e.g. `#22802`) don't get removed. This is because they're not sent to the server, where the URL stripping takes place.

I think the same applies for the answer links: the "Return to Answer" links include the post title in the URL, which results in everything after the question ID getting stripped, including the part of the URL that [results in the page changing if the answer is not on the first page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313428/why-did-the-format-of-full-form-urls-to-answers-change).

**Update:** The development branch of the [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script [now contains a workaround](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/commit/55927e10160fd8b627340ed0cf38149632461d6f#diff-1577392c0b6ec33553046eb648fb1bd8) for the page link issue. (It doesn't resolve the issue with the "Return to Answer" links.) This is planned for the next stable release (1.56).

---

* <sub>As the user was destroyed instead of the post being deleted as spam, it wasn't locked at the same time as being deleted, so it still remains as a live example. The change was applied retroactively to all posts, including the one you linked.</sub>

Comment: Relevant feature: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213201/obscure-the-title-and-text-when-question-is-deleted-by-community-from-spam-offen

Comment: A note for the devs trying to reproduce this: this does not appear to be broken for moderators. At least, I couldn't reproduce it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512 (reported via https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385951)

Comment: @Rob It appears mods are exempt from all attempts at masking spam.

Answer (score 9):

This should work again now.

Enjoy reading all those horribly offensive page 2 answers to those horribly offensive deleted questions!

Comment: Which of the four listed fixes in my answer was implemented? (Or was it a different way?)

Comment: The last one, *kinda*... There's an additional wrinkle in that I wanted answer links to work, so one of two things will happen: if the original URL points to an answer, you just get an answer link (with a slug of %20 - space); if the URL points to the question, the querystring is preserved.

Comment: @Shog: Are you sure the slug stripping is working as intended now? When I click https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234567 it now redirects to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234567/get-your-love-back-91-9928860580 with the full original slug, even when I open it in a private/incognito window. I'm pretty sure it shouldn't do that. :/

Comment: Only kicks in on questions that are *locked* with helpful spam or offensive flags, @IlmariKaronen - avoids a bunch of annoying situations where mods would have had to dispute the flags otherwise.